# Matplotlib bar chart not appearing after slicing array

Tags: python, matplotlib, bar-chart

I tried to make a bar-chart of some numpy float values (read in as string and converted to numpy.float64) and it worked perfectly fine until I sliced the arrays (two lines with #).
The arrays contained 255 values each and after slicing both arrays contained 128 values as expected. They are still the same size and type, and the code works perfectly.
If I change plt.bar(...) to plt.plot(...) the plot appears again, even after slicing the arrays, only plt.bar displays an empty figure.

What could be the problem here? It does not make sense to me

```
    #Pulse amplitude histogram

    bin_pulse_amplitude_indices = np.linspace(0.0, 255.0, num=256)

    pulse_amplitude_histogram_x_axis = (bin_pulse_amplitude_indices - 127) * V_max/127 - V_offset
    pulse_amplitude_histogram_y_axis = np.array(string_data[11:267], dtype=float)

    #pulse_amplitude_histogram_x_axis = pulse_amplitude_histogram_x_axis[pulse_amplitude_histogram_x_axis >= 0]
    #pulse_amplitude_histogram_y_axis = pulse_amplitude_histogram_y_axis[:len(pulse_amplitude_histogram_x_axis)]

    plt.bar(pulse_amplitude_histogram_x_axis, pulse_amplitude_histogram_y_axis)

    plt.title('Pulse Amplitude Histogram')
    plt.xlabel('Amplitude [mV]')
    plt.ylabel('Counts [A]')
    plt.show()
```

[Bar chart working as expected](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MMA3R.jpg)

These are the values displayed in the chart:

```
#   pulse_amplitude_histogram_x_axis   pulse_amplitude_histogram_y_axis
57   -5.511811e+02                    0.000000e+00
58   -5.433071e+02                    0.000000e+00
59   -5.354331e+02                    0.000000e+00
60   -5.275591e+02                    1.000000e+00
61   -5.196850e+02                    1.090000e+02
62   -5.118110e+02                    1.300000e+02
63   -5.039370e+02                    1.000000e+00
64   -4.960630e+02                    0.000000e+00
65   -4.881890e+02                    0.000000e+00
...
```

[Bar chart not appearing after removing hasttags](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4sSpc.jpg)

These are the values after slicing and which get displayed by plt.plot but not by plt.bar:

```
...
57    4.488189e+02    0.000000e+00
58    4.566929e+02    0.000000e+00
59    4.645669e+02    0.000000e+00
60    4.724409e+02    0.000000e+00
61    4.803150e+02    1.630000e+02
62    4.881890e+02    7.500000e+01
63    4.960630e+02    0.000000e+00
64    5.039370e+02    0.000000e+00
65    5.118110e+02    0.000000e+00
...
```

Comment: try to add 'width' param to plt.bar: `plt.bar(pulse_amplitude_histogram_x_axis, pulse_amplitude_histogram_y_axis, 20)`. Usually matplotlib's width is the problem when data disappear completely